# Is being raised a "secular" Jew considered a chillul Hashem?

Tags: halacha, chilul-kidush-hashem

For someone that gets raised in a non-religious household, but who is descended from Jews (at least matrilineally), for them to not be religious, is that considered a chillul Hashem?

Comment: Why should/n’t it be?

Answer (score 3):

OU Torah [295. Chillul Hashem: The prohibition against desecrating God’s Name](https://outorah.org/p/6475) explains the three categories of *Chilul Hashem*

> The Rambam enumerates three types of chillul Hashem. The first is when
>   someone refuses to give up his life when called for. The second is
>   when one commits a sin not because he’s driven by his urges but pretty
>   much out of spite.
>
> The third category is what we typically mean when we talk about
>   chillul Hashem: when someone who should know better acts in a fashion
>   that is perceived to be beneath him. In a Talmudic discussion of what
>   would constitute a chillul Hashem, Rav said it would be if he didn’t
>   pay his butcher on time (Yoma 86a). That’s not such a grievous thing
>   but coming from Rav, it reflects badly on Torah scholars. Each of us
>   at our own level is responsible to strive to act upward and not stoop
>   down.

Someone who is raised in a non-religious manner is  considered a *tinok shenishba* (an infant captured and raised by idolaters).  A person raised non-religious should attempt to learn what Judaism really is and raise their level of behavior. A refusal to learn how they should act can be considered a Chillul, but acting in the way they were raised might not be.

Comment: I’ve also heard something like any time a Jew is a heretic and is seen by a gentile it could be considered a form of chillul hashem.

Comment: @Fei23 Many of the Jews who insist on being anti-Semitic nowadays would also be doing Chillul Hashem as on many college campuses or political action groups.

Comment: @Fei23 Sure that's a shondah fun die Goyim